# jquery counting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I wondering if it is possible to count the number of elements using jquery and then using that prefix the element with a number, so for example I have 2 selects on a page, is it possible to count the selects and then give the selects, a class e.g.,

`<select class="1">`
`<select class="2">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, something like:

```
$("select").each( function (i) {
   $(this).addClass( "select_" + i ); //Classes can't start with a number.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("select").each(function(i, sel) {
    $(sel).addClass("class-" + i);
}
```

Edit: forgot classes can't start with a number.

Comment: I would make this something like `addClass( 'c'+i )` since it's not legal to start a class name with a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('prefix_' + (index + 1));
});
```

Note that a class name cannot start with a number so **make sure** the class name starts with a letter and then put the index.